# How to stop website URL from overspilling margins in knitted rmd document

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am writing a report in rmd and knitting the report to HTML. In my references section, I have website URL's that spill over the margins of the report when it is knit, meaning you have to scroll to the side to see the whole URL. How do I stop this from happening?

I have tried the code below, however it works on all normal text but not on URLs.

```
`</style>
div.main-container {
  max-width: 1300px !important;
}
</style>`
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.